# Virtual properties in TYPO3 extbase domain models?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to use a virtual domain model property in TYPO3 9.5.x that doesn't have a database field representation but I can't get it to work.

My model looks like this

```
class Project extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {
   /**
     * participants
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $participants;

    ...

    /**
     * Returns the participants
     *
     * @return string $participants
     */
    public function getParticipants()
    {
        $this->participants = "foo";

        return $this->participants;
    }
}
```

I do see the property when I debug the model but it's always `null` as if it doesn't even recognise the getter method `getParticipants()`.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Already added a database field to `ext_tables.sql` and the TCA, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is `null` because that's the state when the Extbase debugger inspects it. Notice that the Extbase debugger knows nothing about getters and also does not call them.

So if you want to initialize your property you must do this at the declaration time:

```
protected $participants = 'foo';
```

Comment: Yeah, noticed that too. So I can't debug a virtual property with the Extbase debugger as it doesn't call the getters? What I'm basically trying to do is returning an array in the getter method based on the `uid` of the model entry.

Comment: Well, you can do this just fine, you just can't preview something which does not exist. A similar example is the `FileReference` in TYPO3 which has a lot of useful getters which cannot be inspected.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this property by simpy accessing it.
In Fluid, if you use `<f:debug>{myModel}</f:debug>`, you will see `NULL` for your property.

But if you directly use `<f:debug>{myModel.participants}</f:debug>`, you will see 'foo'.

Comment: Thanks Naderio, that did the trick when I tried exactly that after reading @Mathias Brodalas comment above. Thanks!